# Syntax error when trying to import table

Tags: mysql, database, import, syntax

I'm trying to import a table from a database to another but keep getting this error

the command:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO epdbraid.spawnpoints ( 
    id, spawn_id, lat, lon, despawn_time, updated 
) 
SELECT 
    0, 
    CAST(CONV(id,16,10) AS INTEGER), 
    latitude, longitude, latest_seen, last_scanned 
FROM rocketmapdb.spawnpoint;
```

The error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER), latitude, longitude, latest_seen, last_scanned FROM rocketmapdb.spawnp' at line 1

sql version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO epdbraid.spawnpoints ( 
    id, spawn_id, lat, lon, despawn_time, updated 
) 
SELECT 
    0, 
    CAST(CONV(id,16,10) AS  UNSIGNED ), 
    latitude, longitude, latest_seen, last_scanned 
FROM rocketmapdb.spawnpoint;
```

You can try above code.

Comment: this worked thank you very much!